Enriching serilog logs with Session throws 'Session has not been configured for this application or request.' error
When creating a Serilog ILogEventEnricher everything works fine until I try to access session.  Doing so throws the following error:
Session has not been configured for this application or request.
Eventually, I created a new Asp.Net MVC Application for repro and added session and serilog with everything working fine.
Then when I added the enricher I can get the httpcontext but the second I look at session it still throws the error.
Any ideas as to why session is not accessible or if there is a way around this?  I know I could use middleware but I'm trying to get it to work with the enricher.
Here's my Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HttpContextEnricher>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, serviceProvider, configuration) =>
{
    var contextEnricher = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpContextEnricher>();
    configuration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
        .Enrich.With(contextEnricher);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Here's my controller accessing session fine:
_logger.LogInformation("Index called");

var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

if (context is null)
{
    return View();
}

try
{
    var session = context.Session;
    var test = session.GetString("test");

    if (test == null)
         session.SetString("test", "test");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
}
return View();

Here's my enricher:
public class HttpContextEnricher(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

            if (context is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var session = context.Session;
            var test = session?.GetString("test");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


downvoting stamps out screenshots; thanks for fixing. Will remove my initial comment, and will remove this when you've seen it

Enrichers run on the client thread in the call stack of the Log statement, just running your code before pacing them into an [effectively] immutable LogEvent structure. If stuff throws or acts wierd, that's indepdent of Serilog

The exception is thus about you using a HttpContextAccessor that belongs to a different request (that is no longer active)

In general, people tend to use LogContext.Push (search for it and/or Enrich.FromLogContext to pull things out of the context for inclusion in log statements

Ok so you're saying that even though I can access the HttpContext, that it's stale and that's why session isn't attached to it?

Pretty much - the contract that ASP.NET is giving you is that each request creates a fresh controller instance, and the HttpContextAccessor that you're resolving is in the context of that single request (and will start throwing the second the request processing context is cleaned up)


and that's why session isn't attached to it?
Exceptions from Enrichers are trapped on the basis that you don't want a random log config bug preventing your milion dollar order being saved. (The SelfLog mechanism will report the exception)

